# Error while uploading photo from Angular application to .NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-mvc, typescript, asp.net-core

I'm getting internal service error when I'm trying to upload image using angular application. i was using ng2- file upload. Could you help me fix the code?

Photo-editor.Component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Photo } from 'src/app/_models/Photo';
import { FileUploader } from 'ng2-file-upload';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/_services/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-photo-editor',
  templateUrl: './photo-editor.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./photo-editor.component.css']
})
export class PhotoEditorComponent implements OnInit {
@Input() photos: Photo[];

 uploader: FileUploader;
   hasBaseDropZoneOver = false;
   baseUrl = environment.apiUrl;

    constructor(private authService: AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.initializeUploader();
  }

  fileOverBase(e: any): void {
    this.hasBaseDropZoneOver = e;
  }

  initializeUploader()
  {
    this.uploader = new FileUploader({
    url: this.baseUrl + 'users/' + this.authService.decodedToken.nameid + '/photos',
    authToken: 'Brearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token'),
    isHTML5: true,
    allowedFileType: ['image'],
    removeAfterUpload: true,
    autoUpload: false,
    maxFileSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024

    });

    this.uploader.onAfterAddingFile = (file) =>
    {
      file.withCredentials = false;
    };
  }
}
```

photo-editor.component.Html

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-2" *ngFor="let photo of photos">
    <img src="{{photo.url}}" class="img-thumbnail p-1" alt="">
    <div class="text-center">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm">Main</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="row">
 
  <div class="col-md-3">

      <h3>Select files</h3>

      <div ng2FileDrop
           [ngClass]="{'nv-file-over': hasBaseDropZoneOver}"
           (fileOver)="fileOverBase($event)"
           [uploader]="uploader"
           class="well my-drop-zone">
          Base drop zone
      </div>

      Multiple
      <input type="file" ng2FileSelect [uploader]="uploader" multiple  /><br/>

      Single
      <input type="file" ng2FileSelect [uploader]="uploader" />
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-9" style="margin-bottom: 40px">

      <h3>Upload queue</h3>
      <p>Queue length: {{ uploader?.queue?.length }}</p>

      <table class="table">
          <thead>
          <tr>
              <th width="50%">Name</th>
              <th>Size</th>
              <th>Progress</th>
              <th>Status</th>
              <th>Actions</th>
          </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let item of uploader.queue">
              <td><strong>{{ item?.file?.name }}</strong></td>
              <td *ngIf="uploader.options.isHTML5" nowrap>{{ item?.file?.size/1024/1024 | number:'.2' }} MB</td>
              <td *ngIf="uploader.options.isHTML5">
                  <div class="progress" style="margin-bottom: 0;">
                      <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" [ngStyle]="{ 'width': item.progress + '%' }"></div>
                  </div>
              </td>
              <td class="text-center">
                  <span *ngIf="item.isSuccess"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></span>
                  <span *ngIf="item.isCancel"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i></span>
                  <span *ngIf="item.isError"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></span>
              </td>
              <td nowrap>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs"
                          (click)="item.upload()" [disabled]="item.isReady || item.isUploading || item.isSuccess">
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span> Upload
                  </button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs"
                          (click)="item.cancel()" [disabled]="!item.isUploading">
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></span> Cancel
                  </button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"
                          (click)="item.remove()">
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Remove
                  </button>
              </td>
          </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>

      <div>
          <div>
              Queue progress:
              <div class="progress" >
                  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" [ngStyle]="{ 'width': uploader.progress + '%' }"></div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-s"
                  (click)="uploader.uploadAll()" [disabled]="!uploader.getNotUploadedItems().length">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span> Upload all
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-s"
                  (click)="uploader.cancelAll()" [disabled]="!uploader.isUploading">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></span> Cancel all
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-s"
                  (click)="uploader.clearQueue()" [disabled]="!uploader.queue.length">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Remove all
          </button>
      </div>

  </div>

</div>

<br><br>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">Response</div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <!-- {{ response }} -->
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BsDropdownModule} from 'ngx-bootstrap/dropdown';
import {TabsModule} from 'ngx-bootstrap/tabs';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import {JwtModule} from '@auth0/angular-jwt';
import { FileUploadModule } from 'ng2-file-upload';

import { NgxGalleryModule } from 'ngx-gallery-9';
import { NavComponent } from './nav/nav.component';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {AuthService} from './_services/auth.service';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './register/register.component';
import {ErrorInterceptorProvider} from './_services/error.interceptor';
import { MemberListComponent } from './members/member-list/member-list.component';
import { ListsComponent } from './lists/lists.component';
import { MessagesComponent } from './messages/messages.component';
import {appRoutes} from './routes';
import {UserService} from './_services/user.service';
import {MemberCardComponent} from './members/member-card/member-card.component';
import {MemberDetailComponent} from './members/member-detail/member-detail.component';
import {MemberDetailResolver} from './_resolver/member-detail.resolver';
import { MemberListResolver } from './_resolver/member-list.resolver';
import {MemberEditComponent} from './members/member-edit/member-edit.component';
import {MemberEditResolver} from './_resolver/member-edit.resolver';
import {PreventUnsavedChanges} from './_guards/prevent-unsaved-change.guard';
import {PhotoEditorComponent} from './members/photo-editor/photo-editor.component';


// tslint:disable-next-line: typedef
export function tokenGetter()
{
   return localStorage.getItem('token');
}
@NgModule({
   declarations: [
      AppComponent,
      NavComponent,
      HomeComponent,
      RegisterComponent,
      MemberListComponent,
      ListsComponent,
      MessagesComponent,
      MemberCardComponent,
      MemberDetailComponent,
      MemberEditComponent,
      PhotoEditorComponent
   ],
   imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      HttpClientModule,
      FormsModule,
      NgxGalleryModule,
      FileUploadModule,
      BrowserAnimationsModule,
      TabsModule.forRoot(),
      BsDropdownModule.forRoot(),
      RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
      JwtModule.forRoot({
         config: {
            tokenGetter : tokenGetter,
            allowedDomains : ['localhost:5000'],
            disallowedRoutes: ['localhost:5000/api/auth']
         }
      })
   ],
   providers: [
      AuthService,
      ErrorInterceptorProvider,
      UserService,
      MemberDetailResolver,
      MemberListResolver,
      MemberEditResolver,
      PreventUnsavedChanges
   ],
   bootstrap: [
      AppComponent
   ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Error:

> Failed to determine the https port for redirect.
> fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
>
> An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
>
> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> at MyApp.api.Controllers.PhotosController.AddPhotoForUser(Int32 userId, PhotoForCreationDto photoForCreationDto) in C:\MyApp\myapp.api\Controllers\PhotosController.cs:line 68
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

Comment: Please post the PhotosController.cs source code, because the exception is in the backend .net code.

Comment: Make sure all the not nullable properties having proper value of photoForCreationDto